# in __init__ raise TypeError("%s() got an unexpected keyword argument '%s'" % (cls.__name__, kwarg))

Tags: python, django

```
board = Board(name='Django', description='This is a board about Django.')    

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/babak/myproject/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 501, in __init__
    raise TypeError("%s() got an unexpected keyword argument '%s'" % (cls.__name__, kwarg))
TypeError: Board() got an unexpected keyword argument 'description'
```

Comment: You don't show us what `Board` is, but its `__init__` method does not accept a `description` argument

Comment: i wanna try to build modal api from there in terninal https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/09/11/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-2.html

Comment: My answer still stands... Your implementation of `Board.__init__` does not accept a `description` argument.

Comment: You *need to show the definition of Board*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it looks like your function `Board` does not recognize `description` as a parameter. 
That means, your function does not accept the respective parameter.

It's better that you remove the `description` parameter.

Comment: 1. It's clear that `Board` is a class, not a function (it's a Django Model to be precise). 2. `description` should probably be **added** to `__init__`, not removed from the call to `Board`

Comment: You're probably right. Thanks.